# How can I split strings in a column only when a certain word occurs?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, split

I would like to only retain the part after the word 'in' if it occurs in a row of a column. The problem is that if this word does not occur in the row, its original value is replaced by NaN. I would like to keep the original values if the word 'in' does not appear.

I have tried splitting the string using str.split on the column 'city':

```
    Rotterdam
    Den Haag
    Postcode 2288 in Rijswijk
    Postcode 2511 in Den Haag Centrum
    Delft
```

```py
df.city.astype(str).str.split('in').str[1]
```

Actual results:

```
    NaN
    NaN
    Rijswijk
    Den Haag Centrum
    NaN
```

Expected results:

```
    Rotterdam
    Den Haag
    Rijswijk
    Den Haag Centrum
    Delft
```

Comment: Is possible multiple `in` in column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is replace missing values by original column:

```
df['new'] = df.city.astype(str).str.split(' in ').str[1].fillna(df.city)
print (df)
                                city                new
0                          Rotterdam          Rotterdam
1                           Den Haag           Den Haag
2          Postcode 2288 in Rijswijk           Rijswijk
3  Postcode 2511 in Den Haag Centrum   Den Haag Centrum
4                              Delft              Delft
```

Or select last values in lists by `-1` - solutions working same if only one `in` in data:

```
df.city.astype(str).str.split(' in ').str[-1]
```

Another solution by @Jon Clements is use [`Series.str.rpartition`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rpartition.html):

```
df.city.str.rpartition(' in ')[2]
```

Comment: Your second example (as long as the condition holds true) - is probably better written as: `df.city.str.rpartition('in')[2]`